# ESRI License Initialize & Binding Failure

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.2

Despite following guidance about how to first bind, then initialize a licence for a standalone WinForm uses some arcobjects, I still get the "80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class" error once I call GxDialogClass().  When debugging, the status object beneath comes back as licence checked out - so it successfully binds AND gains a licence.  Yet the 80040111 indicates that I haven't.

We are running ArcGIS 10.2.1.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ProductCode.Desktop);
IAoInitialize aoInitialize = new AoInitializeClass();
var status = aoInitialize.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced);
IGxObjectFilterCollection dialog = new GxDialogClass();
```

Any ideas?

Matthew

Comment: I think you are conflating two different methods of initialization, just use the newer RuntimeManager.Bind method and not the older IAoInitialize method.

Comment: What is the result of the IAoInitialize.Initialize call? Also, when on Desktop, make sure your program runs as 32-bit (set the Platform target to x86).

Comment: @blah: I thought runtime binding and licence checkout are two separate things aren't they? I believe you need to do both as indicated [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00460000002w000000)

Comment: I don't think so; unless you need to check out specific extensions, runtime binding is all you need.

Comment: Binding isn't enough unfortunately - it tells me that I don't have the necessary licence installed - you are merely telling the licence initializer which ArcGIS install version to use (AFAIK).  Although there is a BindLicence call.  This has the same behaviour as calling the AOInitialize.

Comment: Yeah, BindLicense does indeed call AoInitialize under the covers. It also translates its return codes into exceptions.

Comment: When using the SDK for ESRI the AOInitialize code is already laid out in the template... personally I've never used bind, the aoInitialize.Initalize looks fine. Is everything setup properly in ArcGis Administrator (license server path etc..)?

Answer (score 3):

This is all I need to get things going in a standalone .NET app. We have a floating license server rather than individual licenses though, I'm not sure if that matters:

```
if (ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.ActiveRuntime == null)
  ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop);
```

Comment: Tried this approach, no luck. It is embedded deep into an extensively modularised admin app.  Have a hunch there may is threading nastiness introduced by Infragistics GridView controls being using.  If BindLicense method is called in the program Main method, then errors occur in GridViews when trying to render bitmap icons into the grid (image.get_width() - invalid parameter etc.). Discussions on forums for get_width errors points towards other threads disposing of images before the GridView gets to the image.  Why should initialising a licence before rendering the grid affect it?

Comment: ESRI objects are not thread safe. If you initialize a license on the main thread and try to use it in a worker thread there's no guarantee it will work. Any meaningful functions in ESRI must have an initialized license to work, if they don't they will return an error. That's the way that they do it and you can work with it or go open source - your choice.